# PLSQL silently adding and dropping column

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

So, in my PL/SQL code, I added a column in the beginning and dropped the column at the end. 
And when I run it on SQLPLUS, it says "table altered".
is there any way to remove it?

I want to add and drop a column without saying "table altered".

Comment: So you don't want that confirmation message?

Comment: Adding and dropping a column seems like a peculiar way of doing anything. You do know that column will be visible to any other program accessing that table for the duration of your script's elapsed time? Probably the question you should be asking is, *"how can I achieve << whatever it is you're doing >> without adding and dropping a column every time I run my script?"*

Comment: In addition to what APC mentioned, doing this might invalidate objects that depend on the table, and - like all DDL - will commit any open transaction in your session, which you might not be expecting. (You would also have to use dynamic SQL to do this in PL/SQL, and it wouldn't give that feedback - which is generated by the client - so it doesn't sound like you are really talking about PL/SQL code.)

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't have any "table altered" message. (If you did this in PL/SQL it would indeed be silent.) Perhaps you meant SQL\*Plus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

`SQL> set feedback off`

at the beginning of your session.

*Whenever your want to display such messages again, you could use `on` option by replacing `off` in the command.*

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
  DROP COLUMN <column name>;
```

before that, you have set the feedback off

```
set feedback off
```